# AWS and G Suite SPF records

Tags: domain-name-system, email-server, spf

I may be going about this all wrong, if so please point me to the nearest learning resource.
I currently have a G Suite account for handling email addresses for my domain (so I currently just have `admin@mydomain.com`).  I have an app hosted at `mydomain.com` and plan on sending out some user verification emails (from `verify@mydomain.com`), so I signed up for an AWS SES account to handle the mailing.

I would like to do what I can to prevent spam coming from my domain, and I sort of understand that SPF records enable me to do that.  So the question is, as there can only be one such record, how do I set it up for my use case?  Do I set it up to allow only stuff sent through amazonses, which I believe would look like

```
v=spf1 include:amazonses.com -all
```

or do I do it for G Suite?  or neither, or both?

In my mind, I think it should just be the AWS record since that is my outgoing, but I don't want it to prevent incoming mail to my G Suite accounts.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to include each MTA that might send email on behalf of your domain. Start with the soft fail operator `~all` to check everything is working (headers may give some clues), then move on to the hard fail operator `-all`.

```
v=spf1 include:_spf.google.com include:amazonses.com ~all
```

[Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sender_Policy_Framework) has a good primer on SPF, including what soft/hard fail mean. There's also an interesting analysis of the number of lookups [here](https://www.onlineaspect.com/2009/03/20/too-many-dns-lookups-in-an-spf-record/).

**Qualifiers**

NB: this section copied directly from Wikipedia.
Each mechanism can be combined with one of four qualifiers:

- `+` for a PASS result. This can be omitted; e.g., `+mx` is the same as `mx`.
- `?` for a NEUTRAL result interpreted like NONE (no policy).
- `~` (tilde) for SOFTFAIL, a debugging aid between NEUTRAL and FAIL. Typically messages that return a SOFTFAIL are accepted but tagged.
- Use `-` (minus) for FAIL, the mail should be rejected (see below).

Comment: Thanks!  This pretty much answers it for me.  So the idea is that this only allows those severs listed to send emails with `mydomain.com` extension, and any others would fail (well, soft fail, whatever that means vs hard fail, but I can figure that out on my own I think)?  How many servers can I list here, is there a limit?

Comment: Yes, there's a limit of 10 DNS lookups. Note that `_spf.google.com` winds up being four DNS lookups because of how it's constructed.

Comment: Handy to know.  May I ask how to discover that?

Comment: I've expanded my answer with links to useful resources.